# QField display glitch

Tags: qfield

I am using QField v1.8.4 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 running Android 10.

Sometimes when editing an existing feature, the text in a text box widget appears to be duplicated and slightly offset, making it appear blurry. If you then try to edit the text, it appears that the existing text stays and your new text overwrites it. You therefore cannot see properly what you are editing. After saving, the text appears correctly, with edits applied.

Is this a known issue, and if so, is there a solution?

Comment: It seems premature to close this post. It may be a known issue rather than a bug.